# GWT new EntityProxy in @OneToOne with another EntityProxy from server

Tags: gwt

I am just creating a new Proxy:

```
     LayoutExampleRequest r = requestFactory.employeeRequest();
     DepartmentProxy d  = r.create(DepartmentProxy.class);
     r.save(d);
     departmentEditor.editProxy(d, r);
```

Then pass the Proxy and the Request(LayoutExampleRequest ) to my editor

```
      driver.edit(proxy, request);
```

Until here ! everything works as espected. I can save Department objects with null EmployeeProxy. Now iam getting with a suggest box Proxys of EmployeeProxy from the server.

```
        search = new SuggestBox(new SuggestOracle() {
        @Override
        public void requestSuggestions(final Request request,final Callback callback) {
            System.out.println(request.getQuery());

            //ignore less than 3
            if(request.getQuery().length() > 3){
                 requestFactory.employeeRequest().search(request.getQuery()).fire(new Receiver<List<EmployeeProxy>>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<EmployeeProxy> response) {

                        List<MySuggestion<EmployeeProxy>> suggestions = new ArrayList<MySuggestion<EmployeeProxy>>();
                        for(EmployeeProxy e:response){
                            MySuggestion<EmployeeProxy> suggestion = new MySuggestion<EmployeeProxy>();
                            suggestion.setModel(e,e.getFirstName(),e.getFirstName()+" "+e.getLastName());
                            suggestions.add(suggestion);
                        }
                        callback.onSuggestionsReady(request, new Response(suggestions));
                    }
                 });
            }
        }
    });
```

MySuggestion is a wrapper class to handle the EmployeeProxy.

Now i want to add this EmployeeProxy to my DeparmentProxy since i have a @OneToOne on JPA.

```
        search.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<SuggestOracle.Suggestion>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Suggestion> event) {             
            MySuggestion<EmployeeProxy> s = (MySuggestion<EmployeeProxy>)event.getSelectedItem();
            proxy.setSupervisor(s.getModel());
        }
    });
```

proxy is the EntityProxy for Department (I sent to my editor) driver.edit(proxy, request);

then i fire the driver:

```
              departmentEditor.getDriver().flush().fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void response) {
            Window.alert("Success");


            // refresh the datagrid
            Range range = dataGrid.getVisibleRange();
            dataGrid.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(range, true); //1st way

                            // create a new DepartmentProxy to bind to the Editor.
            createProxy();

            // change button text
            updateButton.setText("Save");

        }
        @Override
        public void onConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations) {
            for(ConstraintViolation v :violations){
                Window.alert(v.getMessage()+" "+v.getPropertyPath());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
            Window.alert(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

The problem is iam getting ConstraintViolations from the EmployeeProxy, is like the driver atach the EmployeeProxy but with null values.
(Iam validating my Entityes with  JSR-330 )

Dont know how to make a relationship with a new Proxy with other taked from the server. in a @OneToOne relationship

Any help would be nice!

Thank you

/* UPDATE */
Something like this but with editor

```
            final LayoutExampleRequest r = requestFactory.employeeRequest();
    final DepartmentProxy d  = r.create(DepartmentProxy.class);

    d.setName("Name");
    d.setService(Service.CONTRACT_MANAGMENT);
    // get some random employee
    requestFactory.employeeRequest().findById(1).fire(new Receiver<EmployeeProxy>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(EmployeeProxy response) {
            d.setSupervisor(response);
            r.save(d).fire(new Receiver<DepartmentProxy>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DepartmentProxy response) {
                    Window.alert("Kidding me! why editor cant get it work =p?");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i put on my editor properties of the EmployeeProxy so when a user select the employeproxy would see information about it, so i delete them and then do the same and now works.

Is like GWT when detects properties from another proxy on the editor thinks you will fill it. And the line:

proxy.setSupervisor(s.getModel());

doesn't works.